# Integrate pdf preview on Kile

Tags: preview, live-preview

Has Kile a integrate pdf preview like Texmaker?
If so, how can I active this function?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it has. Menu Settings, point "Show Document Viewer".

Comment: It doesn't have this option.

Comment: It does: https://i.imgur.com/M7fusxU.png

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in the menu Settings called "Show Document Viewer".

Checking the [changelog of Kile](https://github.com/KDE/kile/blob/master/ChangeLog), it seems to be a new feature of Kile 3:

```
version 2.1 -> 3.0 beta 1

Features:
- New live preview feature
- Integration of Okular viewer
- Customizable user menu
```